# Execute exe as admin through cygwin

Tags: windows-7, linux, cygwin, administrator

I am executing an exe in Windows 7 by logging into it from cygwin.
How do i execute it as admin?

Here is the command:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/autopkg_full
env "CommonProgramFiles(x86)"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files" /bin/bash -c '"C:/exefolder/AutoPKG.exe" 1> autopkg.log 2>&1; echo $? > build.txt'
```

I have already made the exe "Run as administrator" by changing its properties in compatibility settings, but that doesn't seem to solve.

Comment: how do you login in cygwin ?

Comment: @matzeri ssh as a non-admin user.